# Dividing two numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a question about a small exercise (in JavaScript) regarding the division of two numbers.
I succeeded but I have three conditions that I do not succeed:

- I have to divide the largest number by the smallest one, not the first by the second.
- I can't divide by 0. I need to warn the user with a message box.
- I can allow negative numbers.

```js
function calculate() {
  var a = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  
  try {
    if (a == '' || b == '' || a == 0 || b == 0) {
      alert("Enter A Value Greater Than 0");
    } 
    
    else {
      var A = Number(a);
      var B = Number(b);
      var C = 0;
      var output = "";
      
      if  ( C = A / B)  {
        output = "" + A + "/" + B + "=" + C;
      }
      
      var element = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
    }
  }
    catch(err) {
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num1" />
<input type="number" id="num2" />
<button type="button" onclick="calculate()" >Calc</button>
<span id="output"></span>
```

Comment: So what is the problem? What goes wrong? Are errors reported? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: So, which part exactly are you struggling with? Is it just the "divide the largest number by the smallest one" part?

Comment: I made you a snippet.

Comment: `I can allow negative numbers.` can or cannot?

Comment: DBS, This was my question. Is allright now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a revised version

- You already had alerts with 0 so I added the max/min
- The code already allows negative numbers
- `if  ( C = A / B)  {` is not useful. It is always true if you have tested for 0 before
- Not possible to divide by 0 since you do not allow 0
- `var element = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;`  - no need to set a value with that statement. Setting innerHTML returns undefined so element is not useful

```js
function calculate() {
  let a = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  let b = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  if (a == '' || b == '' || (a == 0 && b == 0)) {
    alert("Enter a value greater or less  than 0");
    return; // leave
  }  
  let A = Math.max(+a,+b);
  let B = Math.min(+b,+a);
  
  console.log("A",A,"B",B)
  
  if (B===0) {
    alert("This would result in division by 0");
    return 
  }
  let C = A / B;
  document.getElementById("output").textContent = "" + A + "/" + B + "=" + C;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num1" />
<input type="number" id="num2" />
<button type="button" onclick="calculate()" >Calc</button>
<span id="output"></span>
```

Comment: Thnks plungjan. It is perfect!

Comment: Excuse me, I'm a little confused.

Comment: Excuse me, I'm a little confused. When I enter -5 / 0 I get the error ( Enter a value greater or less than 0 ) and it is correct. When I should perform 0 / -5 = 0 (this is not a division by 0) I receive the same error and not the result 0.

Comment: About the answer: I managed to control the first one, it worked, and I approved it. I didn't know you could only aprove an answer. Now I know.

Comment: You must be able to enter all numbers. When dividing by 0 you have to catch it and show an appropriate message. In all other cases you have to show the result.
The program must divide the highest number by the lowest number. For example, if you enter -5 and 0, then 0/-5 must be executed and the result is 0.
I look forward to your reply tomorrow.

Comment: Het is aardig van je om je tijd met mij te verdoen.
Misschien kan ik niet goed in het engels uitleggen wat ik bedoel.
Ik heb nog steeds hetzelfde probleem met  oplossing. Als ik -5 en 0 ingeeft, krijg ik een foutmelding dat je niet kan delen door 0 terwijl je 0/-5 zou moeten doen en dit is geen deling door 0.
Als ik bijvoorbeeld -5 en 0 ingeef dan geeft  programma de melding "Niet delen door 0". Maar je deelt dan 0 door -5 en het resultaat is dan 0. Dat zou dus mogelijk moeten zijn en je hoort hier geen foutmelding te krijgen.

Comment: Ik krijg dit niet. input van 0,-5 of -5,0 geven beide `A: 0,  B: -5` met resultaat `0/-5=0`. In Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like:

```js
function calculate() {
  var a = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  
  try {
    if (a == '' || b == '' || a == 0 || b == 0) {
      alert("Enter A Value Greater Than 0");
    } 
    
    else {
      var A = Number(a);
      var B = Number(b);
      var output = "";

      if (A >= B) output = "" + A + "/" + B + "=" + A/B;
      else output = "" + B + "/" + A + "=" + B/A;
      
      
      var element = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
    }
  }
    catch(err) {
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num1" />
<input type="number" id="num2" />
<button type="button" onclick="calculate()" >Calc</button>
<span id="output"></span>
```

This solution: allows negative numbers and divide the largest number by the smallest.

Comment: This is another requirement:Always divide the largest number by the smallest, not the first by the second.

Comment: @ICXC I solved this requirement by doing `if (A >= B)` divide a per B, else divide B per A. You said "divide the largest number by the smallest" correct?

Comment: @ICXC No problem happy to help you. If you think answer is correct, please, mark it as valid. Happy coding =)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```js
function calculate() {
    const a = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    const b = document.getElementById("num2").value;

    const A = Number( a );
    const B = Number( b );

    if ( 0 === A || 0 === B ) {
        alert( '"Enter A Value Greater Than 0"' );
    }

    const max = Math.max( A, B );
    const min = Math.min( A, B );
    const C = max / min;

    const output = String( max + "/" + min + "=" + C );
  
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num1" />
<input type="number" id="num2" />
<button type="button" onclick="calculate()" >Calc</button>
<span id="output"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reducing complexity of the code with `parseFloat` which returns a Number unless the argument cannot be converted to a Number in which case a `NaN` (= Not a Number) is returned. The `NaN` can be check for with `isNaN`. If one of the inputs in not a number or the denominator (b) is 0 the calculation can not be performed. The syntax in the line after is just to simplify the code to a single line.

```js
function calculate() {
  let num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
  let num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);

  let a = Math.max(num1, num2);
  let b = Math.min(num1, num2);
  
  if(isNaN(a) || isNaN(b) || b === 0){
    alert("Got invalid value, try again.");
  }else{
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = `${a} / ${b} = ${a / b}`;
  }
}
```

Comment: You missed the max/min and OP is a noob, perhaps leave the template literals to later?

Comment: added the min/max
leaving the template literal in perhaps might be useful in future even for someone else. (wasn't part of question, so shouldn't hurt too much if added; can be easily ignored)

Comment: You could have clicked "copy to answer" and given a [mcve] with the HTML I wrote for OP - alternatively click `[<>]` snippet editor